# How can I get the currently-rendered (SVG) DOM when using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas, svg

I have put together a simple HTML page using Angular which can update an SVG drawing. This all works nicely, and with little effort. However, I want to be able to render the SVG to a PNG file in-browser for easy download and reuse.

The SVG drawing is set up like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512" height="512" id="svg">
  <linearGradient id="background-gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="{{background.start}}"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="{{background.end}}"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="primary-gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="{{primary.start}}"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="{{primary.end}}"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="accent-gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="{{accent.start}}"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="{{accent.end}}"/>
  </linearGradient>

  <polygon points="256,0 478,128 478,384 256,512 34,384 34,128" fill="url(#background-gradient)"/>

  <path d="M256,256 m-128,0 a128,128 0 1,1 256,0 a128,128 0 1,1 -256,0 Z M208,224 m-28,0 a28,28 0 1,1 56,0 a28,28 0 1,1 -56,0 Z M304,224 m-28,0 a28,28 0 1,1 56,0 a28,28 0 1,1 -56,0 Z M256,304 m40,0 a40,40 0 1,1 -80,0 Z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#primary-gradient)"/>
  <path d="M216,224 m-16,0 a16,16 0 1,1 32,0 a16,16 0 1,1 -32,0 Z M296,224 m-16,0 a16,16 0 1,1 32,0 a16,16 0 1,1 -32,0 Z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#accent-gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Note that the `stop-color`s in the gradient come from the Angular model. When rendering to a PNG, I create an `Image` with the SVG source, draw that onto a JavaScript-created `<canvas>`, and then convert the `<canvas>` contents to a `data:` URI.

**Unfortunately, this is where things break down.** Using `innerHTML` on the SVG drawing leaves the Angular placeholders in the result, rather than replacing them as expected. This means that all of the gradients turn out to be fully black, as their color values are literally `{{background.start}}`, etc. Obviously this does not produce a good result ☺

So my question is this: *How can I get the SVG DOM that's rendered for display, so I can create the PNG successfully?*

I have been testing this in Chrome v39 and v40 (with various minor versions) on Linux. Reproduce code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="BadgeCreator">
  <head>
    <title>Badge Creator</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('BadgeCreator', [])
  .config( [
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider )
    {   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|data):/);
    }
]);
app.controller('BadgeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var updateDownloadLink = function() {
    var ctx, mycanvas, svg_data, img, child, target = document.getElementById('svg');

    // Construct an SVG image
    svg_data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="' + target.offsetWidth +
               '" height="' + target.offsetHeight + '">' + target.innerHTML + '</svg>';
    console.log(svg_data);
    img = new Image();
    img.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svg_data);

    // Draw the SVG image to a canvas
    mycanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    mycanvas.width = target.offsetWidth;
    mycanvas.height = target.offsetHeight;
    ctx = mycanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Return the canvas's data
    $scope.downloadUrl = mycanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  };

  $scope.background = {start: '#111', end:'#333'};
  $scope.primary = {start: '#c96', end:'#963'};
  $scope.accent = {start: '#3cf', end:'#39c'};

  $scope.$watch('background', updateDownloadLink, true);
  $scope.$watch('primary', updateDownloadLink, true);
  $scope.$watch('accent', updateDownloadLink, true);
}]);
</script>
    <style>
.checkerback {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #eee 75%, #eee), linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #eee 75%, #eee);
  background-size:64px 64px;
  background-position:0 0, 32px 32px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
    </style>
</head>
  <body ng-controller="BadgeController">
    <div style="width:512px; height:512px; margin: 0 auto;" class="checkerback">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512" height="512" id="svg">
        <linearGradient id="background-gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="{{background.start}}"/>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="{{background.end}}"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="primary-gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="{{primary.start}}"/>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="{{primary.end}}"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="accent-gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="{{accent.start}}"/>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="{{accent.end}}"/>
        </linearGradient>

        <polygon points="256,0 478,128 478,384 256,512 34,384 34,128" fill="url(#background-gradient)"/>
        
        <path d="M256,256 m-128,0 a128,128 0 1,1 256,0 a128,128 0 1,1 -256,0 Z M208,224 m-28,0 a28,28 0 1,1 56,0 a28,28 0 1,1 -56,0 Z M304,224 m-28,0 a28,28 0 1,1 56,0 a28,28 0 1,1 -56,0 Z M256,304 m40,0 a40,40 0 1,1 -80,0 Z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#primary-gradient)"/>
        <path d="M216,224 m-16,0 a16,16 0 1,1 32,0 a16,16 0 1,1 -32,0 Z M296,224 m-16,0 a16,16 0 1,1 32,0 a16,16 0 1,1 -32,0 Z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#accent-gradient)"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <p style="text-align: right"><a href="{{downloadUrl}}" download="badge.png">Download image</a></p>
  <p>Background: <input ng-model="background.start">&ndash;<input ng-model="background.end"></p>
  <p>Primary: <input ng-model="primary.start">&ndash;<input ng-model="primary.end"></p>
  <p>Accent: <input ng-model="accent.start">&ndash;<input ng-model="accent.end"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things,

- You can use the [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) to create a live template of your html, and then pass it the current scope to get the rendered html.
- before using the `img` to draw it on the canvas, you must wait until the image is loaded (*use its `onload` event*)
- get the `<svg>` elements width/height attributes to get the dimensions

Refactored code

```js
var app = angular.module('BadgeCreator', [])
  .config([
    '$compileProvider',
    function($compileProvider) {
      $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|data):/);
    }
  ]);
app.controller('BadgeController', ['$scope', '$interpolate',
  function($scope, $interpolate) {
    var target = document.getElementById('svg'),
      ngElement = angular.element(target),
      svgExpression = $interpolate(ngElement.html()),
      updateDownloadLink = function(newval, oldval, scope) {

        var ctx, mycanvas, svg_data, img, child,
          liveHtml = svgExpression(scope),
          svgWidth = parseInt(target.getAttribute('width'), 10),
          svgHeight = parseInt(target.getAttribute('height'), 10),
          svg_data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="' + svgWidth + '" height="' + svgHeight + '">' + liveHtml + '</svg>',
          img = new Image();

        img.onload = function() {
          // Draw the SVG image to a canvas
          mycanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          mycanvas.width = svgWidth;
          mycanvas.height = svgHeight;
          ctx = mycanvas.getContext("2d");
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

          // Return the canvas's data
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.downloadUrl = mycanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          });
        };
        img.src = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svg_data);
      };

    $scope.background = { start: '#111', end: '#333' };
    $scope.primary = { start: '#c96', end: '#963' };
    $scope.accent = { start: '#3cf', end: '#39c' };

    $scope.$watch('background', updateDownloadLink, true);
    $scope.$watch('primary', updateDownloadLink, true);
    $scope.$watch('accent', updateDownloadLink, true);
  }
]);
```

```css
.checkerback {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #eee 75%, #eee), linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #eee 75%, #eee);
  background-size: 64px 64px;
  background-position: 0 0, 32px 32px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="BadgeCreator">

<head>
  <title>Badge Creator</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="BadgeController">
  <div style="width:512px; height:512px; margin: 0 auto;" class="checkerback">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512" height="512" id="svg">
      <linearGradient id="background-gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="{{background.start}}" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="{{background.end}}" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="primary-gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="{{primary.start}}" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="{{primary.end}}" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="accent-gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="{{accent.start}}" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="{{accent.end}}" />
      </linearGradient>

      <polygon points="256,0 478,128 478,384 256,512 34,384 34,128" fill="url(#background-gradient)" />

      <path d="M256,256 m-128,0 a128,128 0 1,1 256,0 a128,128 0 1,1 -256,0 Z M208,224 m-28,0 a28,28 0 1,1 56,0 a28,28 0 1,1 -56,0 Z M304,224 m-28,0 a28,28 0 1,1 56,0 a28,28 0 1,1 -56,0 Z M256,304 m40,0 a40,40 0 1,1 -80,0 Z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#primary-gradient)"
      />
      <path d="M216,224 m-16,0 a16,16 0 1,1 32,0 a16,16 0 1,1 -32,0 Z M296,224 m-16,0 a16,16 0 1,1 32,0 a16,16 0 1,1 -32,0 Z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#accent-gradient)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <p style="text-align: right"><a href="{{downloadUrl}}" download="badge.png">Download image</a>
  </p>
  <p>Background:
    <input ng-model="background.start">&ndash;
    <input ng-model="background.end">
  </p>
  <p>Primary:
    <input ng-model="primary.start">&ndash;
    <input ng-model="primary.end">
  </p>
  <p>Accent:
    <input ng-model="accent.start">&ndash;
    <input ng-model="accent.end">
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```